# Node.js server timeout after ~30 seconds

Tags: node.js, express

I have a index.js route file:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var connection = require('../connection');
    
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.render('layout', { title: 'Movieseat' });
    
      connection.connect();
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `first_name` = "Kees"', function(error, results){
            console.log(
      connection.end();
    });
    
    module.exports = router;
```

This requires my connection.js file:

```
    // make a mysql connection to the database
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'us-cdbr-***-east-04.cleardb.net',
        user     : 'bfe4****0ede74',
        password : '674****9',
        database : 'heroku_****4ee0f0e9102'
    });
    
    module.exports = connection;
```

When I start my server it works fine, but when I reload my localhost and execute the `router.get('/', function(req,res)` it returns the correct record from the database. But then after 30 seconds the server crashes with the following error:

> events.js:
>
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> Error: Quit inactivity timeout

Comment: [this issue](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1223) might help

Comment: It did help a bit. I've ended up using a MySql pool and it seems to be working better now. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/mysql-nodejs-intro/ for the source.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection = require('../connection');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('layout', { title: 'Movieseat' });

  connection.
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `first_name` = "Kees"', function(error, results){
        console.log(
  connection.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

You forgot to close the connection. I've had the same with node-postgres, and it's important to close the connection every time after querying the database.

Greetings, Rafał

Comment: Hey Rafal, I don't know why my `connection.connect()` and `connection.end()` werent coppied correctly in my question (I've editted it now) but that wasn't the problem. I fixed it by pooling the mysql connections though.